# How may we properly format choose within fraction?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am trying to format the document below.

My original goal was to have the choose notation within the fraction notation which a user has helped me solve. Is there a better way to format this document so it looks more appropriate?

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document}

A class has 2n students who must be split up into pairs. We consider two sets of pairs S and T different if at least one pair in the set S isn't a pair in the set T. A pair is unordered, so we consider the pair (1, 2) and (2, 1) to be the same pair. How many different sets of pairs can the class be split up into, in terms of n? (For example, with n = 2, the answer is 3. Sets are {(1, 2), (3, 4)}, {(1, 3), (2, 4)} and {(1, 4), (2, 3)}.)

For the first pair choose $\dbinom{2n}{2}$

For the second pair choose $\dbinom{2n-2}{2}$

For the third pair choose $\dbinom{2n-4}{2}$

The total number  of ways to choose is$\dbinom{2n}{2}$ * $\dbinom{2n-2}{2}$ * $\dbinom{2n-4}{2}$ ... $\dbinom{2}{2}$

Therefore, the total number of different sets of pairs which the class may be split up into, in terms of n, is as follows:

\[ \frac{ \dbinom{2n}{2} * \dbinom{2n-2}{2} * \dbinom{2n-4}{2}...*\dbinom{2}{2} }{n!} \]

  $\frac{2n!}{(2n-2)!2!}$ * $\frac{(2n-2)!}{(2n-4)!2!}$ * ... $\frac{2!}{0!2!}$$\frac{1}{n!}$

= $\frac{2n!}{(2!^nn!}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Document compiled view]

Comment: Use `\frac{1}{n!}\binom{2n}{2}`, it's much clearer.

Comment: Try `\dfrac` instead... PS: in my documentclass `n!` is under the `binom`... and so, it would be nice of you to add a MWE

Comment: please edit your example to be a full document that shows the error, the code you posted produces [this output]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSIos.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here is my output using Online LaTeX overleaf https://imgur.com/a/65xz6I4

Comment: Please make a complete small document, no one can run your example as posted. I used `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \frac{ \dbinom{2n}{2} }{n!} \]
\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that works thank you. I must've missed something in my document.

Comment: Please always post a document that shows the problem, posting code that doesn't have the error makes it hard for anyone to help.

Comment: Thanks this is my first time using LaTeX. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I didn't look at all  of that overleaf link but the page it opens on is full of `{a \choose b}` don't use that syntax in LaTeX!

Comment: I have found dbinom is better than what I was using. Is there a better way to move to the next line besides writing \newline constantly?

Comment: You should almost never use `\newline` in a document. But that's an unrelated question. the site works best if questions are posted separately, but first please fix the example here so someone can answer it.  It is impossible to  an answeer currently.

Comment: delete _all_ the `\newline` you show in that image (they must generate multiple warnings from latex)  to get a new paragraph you just need a blank line.

Comment: Replace `$\dbinom{2n}{2}$ * $\dbinom{2n-2}{2}$ ... ` by a single math expression `$\dbinom{2n}{2} \times \dbinom{2n-2}{2}$`. Also, I'd use `\times`.

Comment: Please, note that `*` is never used in formal mathematics to denote multiplication.

Comment: @TylerRothenberg, see the edited code in the answer below. I inserted some math in the text part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I will structure with an enumeration as `itemize`. Then with an `align*` environment. I'll use `\times` instead of `*`. And I will leave a little space between the question and its resolution.

[image: format]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

A class has $2n$ students who must be split up into pairs. We consider two sets of pairs $S$ and $T$ different if at least one pair in the set $S$ isn't a pair in the set $T$. A pair is unordered, so we consider the pair $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ to be the same pair. 

How many different sets of pairs can the class be split up into, in terms of~$n$? 

\begin{itemize}
\item For example, with $n = 2$, the answer is $3$. The sets are $\{(1, 2), (3, 4)\}$, $\{(1, 3), (2, 4)\}$ and $\{(1, 4), (2, 3)\}$.

\item For the first pair choose $\dbinom{2n}{2}$.

\item For the second pair choose $\dbinom{2n-2}{2}$.

\item For the third pair choose $\dbinom{2n-4}{2}$.

\item The total number  of ways to choose is \[\dbinom{2n}{2}\times \dbinom{2n-2}{2}\times \dbinom{2n-4}{2}\times \dots \times \dbinom{2}{2}.\]
\end{itemize}

Therefore, the total number of different sets of pairs which the class may be split up into, in terms of $n$, is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ \dbinom{2n}{2} \times \dbinom{2n-2}{2} \times  \dots \times\dbinom{2}{2} }{n!} &= \frac{2n!}{(2n-2)!2!} \times \frac{(2n-2)!}{(2n-4)!2!} \times\dots\times \frac{2!}{0!2!}\times \frac{1}{n!}\\
&= \frac{2n!}{2!^nn!}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited a little to insert some math code in text. I hope you agree.

Comment: @Sigur I changed the code like you did! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, revert your edition, because now the code is not good.

Comment: When I changed the image, I already changed the code. It was done before.

Comment: @sigur What have I forgotten?

Comment: Please, revert all your editions and you will see the right code.

Comment: @sigur How do I cancel the changes?

Comment: I will edit again, and you can compare the codes.

Comment: @sigur A tilde between `of` and `n?` must be added to avoid that the `n?` is written on a new line.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few inconsistencies in your input. For instance, symbols that denote mathematical variables or constants should *always* be typeset as math.

Thus use `A class has $2n$ students`; similarly,

```
the pair $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ to be the same pair
```

Even if the result is mostly similar to what you get with `$`, leaving it out can lead to problems, the worst possible is that `(2, 1)` can be split across lines, whereas `$(2, 1)$` can't.

Using `\dbinom` in the presentation of the algorithm is just a waste of space; use it only for special situations, such as the big displayed fraction.

Don't forget *ties*: you don't want that `in the set S` is split just before the `S`, so it's best to type

```
in the set~$S$
```

(with `$`, because it's a math variable).

The asterisk is never used in formal mathematics to denote multiplication. In your case just no symbol is the best.

A factorial that's preceded by a multiplicative factor is best separated from it with a thin space `\,`.

Here's my proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A class has $2n$ students who must be split up into pairs. We consider 
two sets of pairs $S$ and $T$ different if at least one pair in the set~$S$ 
isn't a pair in the set~$T$. A pair is unordered, so we consider the pair
$(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ to be the same pair. How many different sets of pairs 
can the class be split up into, in terms of~$n$? (For example, with $n = 2$, 
the answer is~$3$. Sets are $\{(1, 2), (3, 4)\}$, $\{(1, 3), (2, 4)\}$ and 
$\{(1, 4), (2, 3)\}$.)
\begin{itemize}
\item For the first pair choose $\binom{2n}{2}$,

\item for the second pair choose $\binom{2n-2}{2}$,

\item for the third pair choose $\binom{2n-4}{2}$,

\item and so on.
\end{itemize}

The total number  of ways to choose is
\[
\dbinom{2n}{2}\dbinom{2n-2}{2}\dbinom{2n-4}{2}\dotsm\dbinom{2}{2}.
\]
Therefore, the total number of different sets of pairs which the class may 
be split up into, in terms of~$n$, is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\dbinom{2n}{2}\dbinom{2n-2}{2}\dbinom{2n-4}{2}\dotsm\dbinom{2}{2}}{n!}
&=
\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!\,2!}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(2n-4)!\,2!}\dotsm\frac{2!}{0!\,2!}\frac{1}{n!}
\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2!)^n\,n!}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

with some other fixes: for instance `2n!` is not the same as `(2n)!` and you want the latter.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason we want to itemize the text?  I get that it looks better..

Comment: @TylerRothenberg It is like a “to do list”, itemizing emphasizes this.